# How to collect only logs for an operator setup?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, operator-keyword

I am trying to assist a customer in enabling only log collection for their kubernetes setup. We have documentation that shows this for a Helm chart, but with the operator, I'm not certain where this would go in their deployment files. The customer's deployment file is :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: new-fenestra
  namespace: kelvin-application
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: new-fenestra
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: new-fenestra
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: new-fenestra
      annotations:
        # datadog container autodiscovery
        ad.datadoghq.com/new-fenestra.logs: '[{"source": "new-fenestra", "service": "new-fenestra"}]'
    spec:
      # kubernetes_service_account.kube_sa
      serviceAccountName: application-cluster-ksa
      containers:
      - name: new-fenestra
        image: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/kelvin-application-replacewithenvironment/aurelian/new-fenestra:image-tag-replacement
        command:
          - /app/entry
          - "start"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4000
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "500m"
        env:
        - name: MIX_ENV
          value: "production"
        - name: URL
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: new-fenestra-secrets
              key: host-url

      - name: cloud-sql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy:2.1.0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "512Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
        args:
          - "--private-ip"
          - "--structured-logs"
          - "--port=5432"
          - "kelvin-application-replacewithenvironment:us-central1:aurelianvpc"

        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true

      - name: otel-collector
        image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.71.0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "256Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
        args:
        - --config=/conf/collector.yaml
        env:
        - name: DATADOG_API_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: new-fenestra-secrets
              key: datadog-api-key
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /conf
          name: otel-collector-config
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: collector.yaml
            path: collector.yaml
          name: otel-collector-config
        name: otel-collector-config
```

Here is the agent deployment file with the env vars we recommended in our docs:

```
kind: DatadogAgent
apiVersion: datadoghq.com/v2alpha1
metadata:
  name: datadog-agent
  namespace: kelvin-application
spec:
  global:
    site: us5.datadoghq.com
    credentials:
      apiSecret:
        secretName: datadog-secret
        keyName: api-key
      appSecret:
        secretName: datadog-secret
        keyName: app-key
  override:
    clusterAgent:
      image:
        name: gcr.io/datadoghq/cluster-agent:latest
    nodeAgent:
      image:
        name: gcr.io/datadoghq/agent:latest
      env:
        - name: DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_EVENTS
          value: "false"
        - name: DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_SERIES
          value: "false"
        - name: DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_SERVICE_CHECKS
          value: "false"
        - name: DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_SKETCHES
          value: "false"

  features:
    logCollection:
      enabled: true
      containerCollectAll: false
```

I attempted to add env vars in the agent file

Answer (score 0):

Please use the updated code below for the fix for your issue (hopefully!!)

````
apiVersion: datadoghq.com/v2alpha1
metadata:
  name: datadog-agent
  namespace: kelvin-application
spec:
  global:
    site: us5.datadoghq.com
    credentials:
      apiSecret:
        secretName: datadog-secret
        keyName: api-key
      appSecret:
        secretName: datadog-secret
        keyName: app-key
  override:
    clusterAgent:
      image:
        name: gcr.io/datadoghq/cluster-agent:latest
    nodeAgent:
      image:
        name: gcr.io/datadoghq/agent:latest
      env:
        - name: DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_EVENTS
          value: "false"
        - name: DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_SERIES
          value: "false"
        - name: DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_SERVICE_CHECKS
          value: "false"
        - name: DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_SKETCHES
          value: "false"

  features:
    logCollection:
      enabled: true
      containerCollectAll: false
      containers:
        - name: new-fenestra
          service: new-fenestra```

You forgot to configure logCollection and specify which containers to collect logs from.

In the features section, set logCollection.enabled to true to enable log collection. By default, containerCollectAll is set to false, which means logs will only be collected from the specified containers.

Under features.logCollection.containers, add the containers you want to collect logs from. In this case, you can add the new-fenestra container and specify the service as new-fenestra.

Make sure to apply the modified DatadogAgent deployment file to your Kubernetes cluster for the changes to take effect.

After completing these steps, it should work if not just let me know!
````